# How do I get WMA if index size is greater than window size?

Tags: python-3.x, weighted-average, wma

Is there a way to find the average of numbers if the window size is less than the index?

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
window_size = 4
i = 0
moving_averages = []
while i < len(numbers) - window_size + 1:
    this_window = numbers[i : i + window_size]

    window_average = sum(this_window) / window_size
    moving_averages.append(window_average)
    i += 1

print(moving_averages)
###returns []
```

Comment: The body of the loop is not executed because  when `i = 0`, `len(numbers) - window_size + 1 = 0`. Condition `0 < 0` is `False`.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg Thank you, I was able to figure it out.